# How to kill and restart an akka persistent actor in unit test to see if it retains state

Tags: testing, akka-persistence

In my unit tests, is there a way to kill and then restart a persistent actor to check whether it can properly retain state (and that, for instance, event serialisation/deserialisation works fine)?

Answer (score 4):

```
// Initialize the actor and a probe for the actor 
val probe = TestProbe()
val act = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor], "name")

// send messages to the actor to change state
// Validate that the state has changed

// Send a message to terminate the actor
act ! PoisonPill

// wait for the actor to shutdown 
probe.watch(act)
probe.expectTerminated(act)

// Initialize a new probe and a new instance of the actor, with the assumption 
// that the actor has the same persistence id as the initial one.
// That actor should now be in the same state as before. 

val probeTwo = TestProbe()
val rehydrated = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor], "name")

// Validate the state of the actor. 
// Todo: Put your validation checks here
```

Here is some useful information on how to [test](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/testing.html) actors.

Answer (score 0):

Note: for persistent actors the PoisonPill message is not recomended way to stop an actor. Recomended way is explicit shutdown eg:`system.stop(act)`

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/persistence.html#Safely_shutting_down_persistent_actors